# How to close sweetalert popup from code behind

Tags: c#, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using SweetAlert to show loading popup. I want to close the popup when a process in codebehind is finished, How can I achieve that?

```
function showLoading() {
        swal({
            title: "Loading...",
            text: "Please wait",
            imageUrl: "/content/loader.gif",
            imageHeight: 200,
            imageWidth: 200, 
            button: false,
            closeOnClickOutside: false,
            closeOnEsc: false
        })
    }

 protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "loading", "testLoad()", true);
        beginProcess();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after beginProcess():

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "swal.close()", true);
```

Comment: its not working sir. Seems like swal.close() prevent modal from showing at first and loading popup didn't show. Btw, I try debugging the process and found that the popup get call when beginProcess(); already finished.

Comment: Didn't know what you are doing in beginProcess() so, won't tell you the appropriate solution. Would be helpful if you share it!

Comment: just the code to delete old data and calculate new value to insert  into sql server. `year = int.Parse(Session["Year"].ToString());
 string delquery = @"DELETE FROM Qualify_Product WHERE year = '"+year+"' ";
            db.RunExecuteNonQuery(delquery); List<Products> qProducts = getNewQProductList(); insertQualifyProducts(qProducts);`

Comment: My bad. Actually code behind page load method calls before rendering UI. You can achieve this from ajax. Use ajax start() for showing loader and ajax stop() for closing it.